# Unknown "usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given" error

Tags: php, arrays, usort

today im trying to sort array by passing a variable into its function. I can print and interact with the array just fine, but for some reason i cant pass it to a function.

I've tried printing the array to see if it actually has any data and it turns out it has all the data i need.

Here's where i initialize $filesinfo variable

```
<?php
  $path = 'uploads/'.$file;
  $LastModified = filemtime($path);
  $filesize = filesize($path);
  $filextension = explode(".",$file);
  $filetp = end($filextension);
  $filesinfo[] = array($path, $LastModified, $filesize, $filetp);
  $size = filesize($path);
  $units = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB');
  $power = $size > 0 ? floor(log($size, 1024)) : 0;
  echo number_format($size / pow(1024, $power), 2, '.', ',') . ' ' . $units[$power]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo date("F d Y H:i:s",filemtime("uploads/".$file));?></td>
  <td><?php  $ext = explode(".",$file); echo end($ext);?></td>
  <td class="actions"><?php echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="rename.php?name='.$file.'">Rename</a><form action="main.php" method="POST"> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="del" value="'.$file.'">Delete</button></form>';?></td>
</tr>
<?php
  }
}
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And here's the place where i am trying to pass the $filesinfo to a function and it says that the parameter is null.

```
<?php
print_r($filesinfo);
if ($_GET['sort']==="date" && $_GET['type']==="desc") {
  SortByDate($filesinfo);
}elseif($_GET['sort']=="date" && $_GET['type']=="asc"){
  SortByDateAsc($filesinfo);
}elseif($_GET['sort']=="name" && $_GET['type']=="desc"){
  SortByNameDsc($filesinfo);
}elseif($_GET['sort']=="name" && $_GET['type']=="asc"){
  SortByNameAsc($filesinfo);
}elseif($_GET['sort']=="size" && $_GET['type']=="desc"){
  SortBySizeDsc($filesinfo);
}elseif($_GET['sort']=="size" && $_GET['type']=="asc"){
  SortBySizeAsc($filesinfo);
}elseif($_GET['sort']=="type" && $_GET['type']=="asc"){
  SortByTypeAsc($filesinfo);
}elseif($_GET['sort']=="type" && $_GET['type']=="desc"){
  SortByTypeDsc($filesinfo);
}

}
```

And here's one of my functions.

```
function SortByDate(&$Files) {
usort($Files, function($a, $b) {
return $a['1'] <=> $b['1'];
});
}
```

All of these functions are almost identical they just change the way the content is sorted and returns values. But i still cant put $filesinfo as a parameter even when it is an array.

**UPDATE : Sorry posted wrong function, here's the output from print**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => uploads/bootstrap-45c98b856dc045.zip [1] => 1553512534 [2] => 2705432 [3] => zip ) [1] => Array ( [0] => uploads/pointillist5c94d2e7eec5d.bmp [1] => 1553257191 [2] => 1080054 [3] => bmp ) [2] => Array ( [0] => uploads/sfdes.jpg [1] => 1553265149 [2] => 1246909 [3] => jpg ) [3] => Array ( [0] => uploads/ssser.sql [1] => 1553239646 [2] => 13098 [3] => sql ) [4] => Array ( [0] => uploads/vvv.jpg [1] => 1553263350 [2] => 879394 [3] => jpg ) [5] => Array ( [0] => uploads/wadaw.jpg [1] => 1553264937 [2] => 1246909 [3] => jpg ) [6] => Array ( [0] => uploads/wadawv.mp3 [1] => 1553263463 [2] => 4113874 [3] => mp3 ) )
```

Comment: The error is actually pretty clear. However, your question is lacking the call of usort() - whose parameter is null instead of an array.

Comment: `print_r($filesinfo);` show us the result. `SortByTypeAsc` show us the whole function (or where else the error is coming from)

Comment: I don't see `usort` usage, provide some code for any of `SortBy...` function.

Comment: Sorry, posted wrong function.

Comment: @shushu304 if it was the version, there would be a parsing error at the spaceship operator

Comment: @Areg is this the function where the error is raised?

Comment: Yes, it also doesnt work on any of my other functions

Comment: Can you remove all that other, not-related, code, and just show some code that only contains `SortByDate`, and then calls it a hardcoded list of two elements, so that people can run that code and see the same thing that you're seeing? Nothing else actually bears relevance to your problem, and so all that extra code just confuses the question instead of making it clearer. Giving people a [mcve] goes a _very_ long way to getting your question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so stupid, i switched to xampp and it worked fine. I don't know what was the problem, might have been some request problem.

Answer (score 3):

Description:

> usort — Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function

Declaration:

```
usort ( array &$array , callable $value_compare_func ) : bool
```

The correct way of using [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) is:

```
// comparator which will be passed to usort
function comparator($a, $b) {
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : $a == $b ? 0 : 1;
}

$arr = array(1, 3, 5, 1);

usort($arr, "comparator"); // passing the comparator
```

Comment: @Areg The error clearly says that 1st parameter is null. Just wrap `usort` around `if` statement and see if something unexpected is happening. It might happen due to multiple request. Where did you see this error? In error logs?

Comment: This error just displays on the page, i am using wamp local server

Comment: Let me just confirm weather you wrap it in the following manner: `function SortByDate(&$Files) {if(!empty($Files)){//usort func`?

Comment: @Areg If you have wrapped the usort in OP and still get this error message that means there is another `usort` function on the same page which is causing the issue.